# Why can't I run yarn start?

Tags: terminal, yarnpkg

For a few days I have been getting these messages:

*> yarn run v1.21.1 $ react-scripts start

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "eslint": "^6.6.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of eslint was detected
>   higher up in the tree:
>
> /home/sol/Repository/node_modules/eslint (version: 6.3.0)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
>   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
>   permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /home/sol/Repository/node_modules/eslint is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
>   We hope you find them helpful!
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
>   command.*

I tried everything above, but nothing helps and I'm really upset about this situation because I can't get my code to work.

Can someone help me with easy instructions because I don't have time anymore to try and find a solution to the problem.

Comment: I've had this issue in the past. I've resolved it by deleting `~/node_modules` (the `node_modules` folder in your local user directory.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work.

Comment: Have you used both `npm` and `yarn` in the same directory?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes with npm. Sometimes with yarn. I deleted everything multiple times. Nothing works.

Comment: They're not compatible. Maybe the yarn documentation will help https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks. It was something in my old repository folder who was blocking this thing.

I fixed it by creating a brand new repository folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the problem: 
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"eslint": "^6.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

/Users/elvestrindade/node_modules/eslint (version: 6.2.2)